# VMWare PowerCLI Invoke-VMScript

Tags: powershell, powercli

I would like to Invoke a command on a Remote VM using PowerShell with PowerCLI.

```
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText "cmd /c calc" -ScriptType Bat -VM $VMName -GuestCredential $Credential -Confirm:$false -ea SilentlyContinue
```

Sadly everytime when my command get's invoked an Popup appears telling me "A Program running on this computer is trying to display a message" If click manually on that Popup my Script runs fine, but how can I automate this, so that I can use PowerCLI for this.

The goal is to execute a Binary in Interactive Mode, that processes Automated Tasks, when the Script get's invoked by "Invoke-VMScript"

Comment: This was just an error in adding the command here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with [Interactive Services Detection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me/). Your script is trying to run as interactive in Session 0.

The standard workarounds are creating a schedule task and then triggering it. Or invoking [`psexec.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to the user session with `-i`.